# How to write a dynamic SQL code in Teradata?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, teradata

I am trying to convert this code (which accepts a column name as input, does calculations on the input column and inserts data into a table). Now that I know that we can't pass table/column names through a stored proc or macro, I came to know that we can do it through a dynamic SQL. I am not sure how the syntax should be as I could not find a clear and easy example. Below is my code which needs to be converted:

```
INSERT INTO PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5

                    SELECT 
                                'DURATION_CELL_CURR' AS COLMN,
                                PW_END_DATE,
                                'ACPT' AS TAB,
                                MIN(DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS PER_MIN,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_25,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_50,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_75,
                                MAX(DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS PER_MAX
                    FROM (
                                SELECT PC.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS SEQNUM,
                                 COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                  FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.ACPT_PROD_CVM PC
                                  WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2017-01-17'
                                )A
                                GROUP BY 1,2,3

UNION ALL

                    SELECT 
                                'DURATION_CELL_CURR' AS COLMN,
                                PW_END_DATE,
                                'PROD' AS TAB,
                                MIN(DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS PER_MIN,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_25,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_50,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN DURATION_CELL_CURR END) AS PER_75,
                                MAX(DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS PER_MAX
                    FROM (
                                SELECT PC.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DURATION_CELL_CURR) AS SEQNUM,
                                 COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                  FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.PROD_CVM PC
                                  WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2017-01-17'
                                )B
                                GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Below is my understanding of its conversion in dynamic SQL:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE (IN COL CHAR(50))
(
BEGIN REQUEST
CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL
('
INSERT INTO PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5
                            SELECT
                            '||COL||' AS COLMN,
                            PW_END_DATE,
                            ''ACPT'' AS TAB,
                            MIN( '||COL||') AS PER_MIN,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_25,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_50,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_75,
                            MAX( '||COL||') AS PER_MAX
                            FROM (
                                        SELECT PC.*,
                                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  '||COL||') AS SEQNUM,
                                         COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                          FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.ACPT_PROD_CVM PC
                                          WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2017-01-17'
                                         )A
                            GROUP BY 1,2,3

            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 
                            '||COL||' AS COLMN,
                            PW_END_DATE,
                            ''PROD'' AS TAB,
                            MIN( '||COL||') AS PER_MIN,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_25,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_50,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_75,
                            MAX( '||COL||') AS PER_MAX
                            FROM (
                                SELECT PC.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  '||COL||') AS SEQNUM,
                                 COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                  FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.PROD_CVM PC
                                  WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2017-01-17'
                                )B
                          GROUP BY 1,2,3
')

END REQUEST;
);
```

I understand I have to resolve many errors before this code is run-ready. So one of the first errors I am getting is below:

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this. I have to calculate quantile distribution of 60+ such columns which doing manually is insane.
Much appreciated.
Piyush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pair of parens starting before the `BEGIN` should be removed and all single quotes around strings including the dates must be doubled:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE (IN COL CHAR(50))
BEGIN
CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL
('
INSERT INTO PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5
                            SELECT
                            '||COL||' AS COLMN,
                            PW_END_DATE,
                            ''ACPT'' AS TAB,
                            MIN( '||COL||') AS PER_MIN,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_25,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_50,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_75,
                            MAX( '||COL||') AS PER_MAX
                            FROM (
                                        SELECT PC.*,
                                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  '||COL||') AS SEQNUM,
                                         COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                          FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.ACPT_PROD_CVM PC
                                          WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE = DATE ''2017-01-17''
                                         )A
                            GROUP BY 1,2,3

            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 
                            '||COL||' AS COLMN,
                            PW_END_DATE,
                            ''PROD'' AS TAB,
                            MIN( '||COL||') AS PER_MIN,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_25,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_50,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN  '||COL||' END) AS PER_75,
                            MAX( '||COL||') AS PER_MAX
                            FROM (
                                SELECT PC.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  '||COL||') AS SEQNUM,
                                 COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
                                  FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.PROD_CVM PC
                                  WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  DATE ''2017-01-17''
                                )B
                          GROUP BY 1,2,3
');

END;
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth. I could successfully run your version, but I think I didn't handle the column name properly here `SELECT 
                            '||COL||' AS COLMN,`  and becasue of this I am getting following results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875937/how-to-delete-records-from-a-column-which-belong-to-a-different-data-type

Any workaround for getting the column name instead of its values in the **COLMN**

Comment: I am using `''||COL||'' AS COLMN`
to see if this amends the results.

Comment: @PiyushVerma: Quoting the parameter should fix it.

Comment: In the select statement or in the call statement?
changing `'||COL||' AS COLMN` to `'||'COL'||' AS COLMN` ?

Comment: @PiyushVerma: In fact it should be `SELECT 
''''||COL||''' AS COLMN,
PW_END_DATE,
''ACPT'' AS TAB,
...'`, in the resulting string it must be a`'COL'`. You better assign the SELECT to a variable first, you can easily return it as an OUT-var instead of executing and check if the resulting strinmg is valid.

Comment: `SELECT ''''||COL||''' AS COLMN` doesn't seem will work as it will not get properly highlighted. And I could not get your 2nd suggestion? _"You better assign the SELECT to a variable first, you can easily return it as an OUT-var instead of executing and check if the resulting strinmg is valid."_

Comment: @PiyushVerma: Have a look at the manuals: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_151K/ch03.108.114.html#ww11214369  This also shows Standard SQL complant EXECUTE IMMEDIATE instead of the proprietary SysExecSQL CALL.