# How to delete records from a column which belong to a different data type?

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata, alter

So I inserted few records in a table manually (without using Stored procedure) and rows were fine under a column "**COLMN**". Then I tried to automate it by using dynamic-SQL in stored procedure. Unfortunately I ended up appending rubbish records (entered float in a column which was meant to be Char). How can I delete these selected rubbish records which don't belong?
Here is how my table looks like:

[image]

...And I want to delete those numeric records (from column "**COLMN**") I planned to achieve this by :Altering the table and adding a column for sequence, updating the sequence column, sorting it and accordingly deleting the top or bottom N rows and lastly dropping the column. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5 ADD SEQ_NUM INT;

UPDATE  PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5
SET SEQ_NUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLMN)
```

But we can't use analytical functions like that.

[image]

Let me know if there is an easy way to do it.

Thank you

Piyush

Comment: so do you want to update the column values to null when there are integers or floats? or delete such rows?

Comment: Actually I want to delete those records as they don't make any sense. That is deleting selectively a different data type in the same column. The image you are seeing of the table is the result of this query here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869526/how-to-write-a-dynamic-sql-code-in-teradata/41874251#41874251)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find numeric strings is probably comparing upper and lower case of the column name, if it's numeric both will be the same:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5
WHERE LOWER(COLMN) = UPPER(COLMN) (CASESPECIFIC)
   OR COLMN IS NULL
```

If this returns the correct rows simply change to a DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try to locate the wrong rows in a WHERE condition?

`COLMN` must be a string, because a good content is 'STRETCH_DOLLAR_ADJUSTED'.

From the table cutout you show above, you start with:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5 
WHERE COLMN IS NULL
   OR LEFT(COLMN,1) IN (
  '-'
, '+'
, '0'
, '1'
, '2'
, '3'
, '4'
, '5'
, '6'
, '7'
, '8'
, '9'
);
```

Refine the WHERE condition until you get the rows you intend, and then use that WHERE condition in a DELETE statement.

Or am I getting something wrong?

Marco the Sane .